# Android gradle issue

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies

> Error:Failed to open zip file. Gradle's dependency cache may be
>   corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project
   Re-download dependencies and sync project

I don't know why I getting this error, Anybody help.?

Answer (score 0):

One of your dependencies might be corrupt. You can delete your gradle cache to delete and redownload all dependencies.

```
User\.gradle\caches
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be some issue with a dependency cached by Gradle.You can go to`File->Invalidate Cache and restart`.It will restart android studio and rebuilt the cache.